# C# Why don't I receive any output from the console?

Tags: c#

When I run this code, enter my input, for some reason I do not receive any sort of output.

This is my code:

```
string fruit = Console.ReadLine();
double quantity = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string day = Console.ReadLine();

if (day == "Monday" || day == "Tuesday"|| day == "Wednesday" || day ==     "Thursday" || day == "Friday")
{
    switch (fruit)
    {
        case "banana": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(2.50*quantity,2)); break;
        case "apple": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.20 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "orange": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.85 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "grapefruit" : Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.45 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "kiwi": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(2.70 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "pineapple": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(5.50 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "grapes": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.85* quantity, 2)); break;
        default: Console.WriteLine("error"); break;
    }
}
else if (day == "Saturday" || day == "Sunday")
{
    switch (fruit)
   {
        case "banana": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(2.70 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "apple": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.25 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "orange": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.90 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "grapefruit": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.60 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "kiwi": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.00 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "pineapple": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(5.60 * quantity, 2)); break;
        case "grapes": Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.20 * quantity, 2)); break;
        default: Console.WriteLine("error"); break;
    }
}
```

If any of you could help me out I would be really grateful.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger and stepping through it?

Comment: Try using lowercase or ignore case comparison for the days, you are most likely typing in 'monday' instead 'Monday'.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting output - it's just that the application finishes too quickly for you to see it. Just add the following line at the very end of your method to make your application pause for input before quitting:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

As well you can use 
Console.ReadKey();

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> if you work in Visual Studio to run a program without debugging, so it will stop at the end and console will be closed after you hit any key.